# Set default value to dropdown list angular

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

I want 0th index to to be selected as default in dropdown list angular material.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    name="dashboard"
    (selectionChange)="showDashboard(dashboard)"
    [(ngModel)]="dashboard"
    [(value)]="selected"
  >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let status of CLIENT_STATUS" [value]="status.id">
      {{ status.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Can anyone please tell what has to be done to set the default value on loading of page?

Comment: what is the initial value of ngModel=dashboard?

Comment: I have to set that value. I don't know how to set.

Comment: can i see your component code?

Comment: after loading data in CLIENT_STATUS then you have to assign id of first index to dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

.html file

```
  <form [formGroup]="patientCategory">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <mat-select placeholder="Category" formControlName="patientCategory">
            <mat-option>--</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let category of patientCategories" [value]="category">
                {{category.name}} - {{category.description}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

.ts file

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  patientCategory: FormGroup;

  patientCategories=[{
    id:1,
    name:'name 1',
    description:'description 1'
  },{
    id:2,
    name:'name 2',
    description:'description 2'
  },{
    id:3,
    name:'name 3',
    description:'description 3'
  }]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {

        this.patientCategory = this.fb.group({
            patientCategory: [null, Validators.required]
        });

    const toSelect = this.patientCategories.find(c => c.id == 3);
      this.patientCategory.get('patientCategory').setValue(toSelect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an example: 
HTML file:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Test</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in your TS file set the default value:

```
  selected = 'option1';
```

Comment: I am rendering data from backend. so in that case how to set default value?

Comment: When you get data from backend you should initialize selected property with the value recovered

Comment: I did initialising the value. But still i am not able to achieve that.

Comment: could you provide your ts file please